# Show all image inside folder that has some word?

Tags: php, database, image

could someone help me! I have Name on tabel ex: `"user01-Diana"`

And I have few image file on folder that being rename to ex:
`"user01_20131231_1201.jpg"` and `"user01_20131231_1216.jpg"` and `"user02_20131231_1201.jpg"`

what i want is read that word user01 from table then use it to show all image that has a word "user01" on folder and show it ASC.
could someone help me? i am not really good with php. stay up whole night still didn't get it.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: is `user01` different from `user1`? because your examples are NOT at all explaining what the problem is.

Comment: is the name i.e. "user01-Diana" and the images saved in the same table

Comment: @Mike i try explode it but still cant. im newbie.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry my bad, its all user01.

Comment: @Anamika Yes its on same table anamika.

Comment: did you tried the solution i gave

Comment: @Anamika sorry anamika i guess its my false didn't say about folder.
i want show all image from folder with name user01 on it. in my table only has 1 image "first image". The rest image is user01 image next month.

Comment: @whaku please check ans now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per new modification in the question try the following code.

First get the name you want to fetch records for in a variable, like user01-Diana

```
$name = "user01-Diana";
```

now extract the text against which you want to search the record, like user01

```
$name = substr($name, 0, strpos($name, '-'));
```

now we will create a pattern against which we will have to match the images name in folder,
in this case our patter is, '/user01/'

```
$pattern = "/$name/";
```

now specify the path to your directly form the currnt file in `opendir` function

```
if ($handle = opendir('./userimg')) {
    //here we are matching user01 against the files in the directory
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        //those that get matched will be echoed below
        if(preg_match($pattern, $entry))
            echo "<br />".$entry;
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

---

---

OLD code to match previous requirement

First you will have to extract `user1` from `user01-Diana`

you can do this by,

```
$name = "user01-Diana";

$name = substr($name, 0, strpos($name, '-'));
```

Now you will get `user01` in `$name` variable.

After that you can use the following query.

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM tablename where imagename like '".$name."%'";
```

also if you have data in same table somewhat like as below,

[image]

use the following query

```
Select 
    t1.imagename
from 
    Table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN
    Table1 as t2
ON
    t1.imagename LIKE concat("'", substr(t2.username, 1,(LOCATE("-",t2.username)-1)) , "%'") 
WHERE 
    t1.imagename IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    t1.imagename
```

Comment: omg you help me so much @Anamika, ill try it now. I'll post the result later.

Comment: i try ur code, but it's only show list of image file name on that folder. how to show all image with word user01 in it and sort it ASC.

Comment: My code now like this, and all works just like what i want.
`// Find all files in that folder
$files = glob('../album/'.$idpas.'*');
// Do a natural case insensitive sort, usually 1.jpg and 10.jpg would come next to each other with a regular sort
natcasesort($files);
// Display images
foreach($files as $file) {
   list($idpas,$haripas,$jampas)=split("_",$file);
   echo '<img width="640" height="480" src="' . $file. '" /><br/><center>Foto Pasien '.$namapas.' Tanggal: <strong>'.date("d M Y",strtotime($haripas)).'</strong></center><br />';`

Answer (score 0):

You should have a query to select images from your table where image name will be started with `'user01'`. Your code should be like this:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
$sql = "select column_name as image from your_table where column_name like 'user01%' order by column_name";
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['image'] . '<br />';
}
```